# CakePHP 3: Moved datadir/socket for mysql, now getting SQLSTATE error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I recently moved my mysql database onto a larger partition. To do this I updated the `my.cnf` file and updated the `datadir` and `socket`values then added the following.

```
[client]
socket=/same/as/socket/path
```

And then restarted the mysql server.

I'm able to access my database manually, and none of my schema nor credentials have changed. I'm using CakePHP 3 and when I attempt to access the main page I get:

```
Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

In my config file, I've tried setting `quoteIdentifiers => true` but it has no impact.

Comment: Hard to help you, we need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to edit my php.ini with the new location of the mysql socket. I'm using php-fpm, and had to restart that once the php.ini was updated.